# I have to sort items entered during run time but in different pattern

Tags: vb.net

Items will start with x, y and w and i have get a sorted order with x first in descending order then y in descending and last w in ascending order only items starting with x,y and w will be there.
for eg,

input

```
y1 
w1 
y2 
x1 
x3 
w10 
w19
```

output

```
x3
x1
y2
y1
w1
w10
w19
```

**What I have tried:**

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
    TextBox1.Clear()




End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    ListBox2.Items.AddRange(ListBox1.Items)
    ListBox2.Sorted = True

    Dim StrArray As String() = ListBox2.Items.OfType(Of String).ToArray()


    Dim str1() As String
    Dim str2() As String
    Dim str3() As String


    For i As Integer = 0 To StrArray.Length - 1

        If (StrArray(i).Substring(0, 1) = "x") Then
            str1(i) = StrArray(i)

        ElseIf (StrArray(i).Substring(0, 1) = "y") Then
            str2(i) = StrArray(i)

        Else
            str3(i) = StrArray(i)
            Array.Sort(str3)

        End If


    Next i
    str1 = str1.Reverse
    str2 = str2.Reverse


    ListBox2.Items.AddRange(str1.ToArray)
    ListBox2.Items.AddRange(str2.ToArray)
    ListBox2.Items.AddRange(Array.Sort(str3))


End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You need to either create a class that implements the `IComparer(Of String)` interface or a method with a signature matching the `Comparison(Of String)` delegate.  You can then call a `Sort` method that takes one of those to do the comparing.  That's gives you something to research so you should do that and come back if you have issues with the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in a console project. It's LINQ.

1. The first Select() method split each line into a type with Head and Value, eg. Head = x, Value = 3.
2. The second OrderBy() method sort ascendingly the array based on the value of Head (the first character). X is given 1 score, Y is given 2 score and W is given 3 score. So it sorts with this order x -> y -> w.
3. The third ThenBy() method is another sort ascendingly based on the value of Value (the number). X and Y are given negative value while w is given positive value.
4. Last Select() method combines the Head and Value back.

   Module Module1

   ```
   Sub Main()

       Dim arr = {"y1", "w1", "y2", "x1", "x3", "w10", "w19"}

       Dim sortedArr = arr _
           .Select(Function (x) New With { .Head = x(0), .Value = Convert.ToInt32(x.SubString(1, x.Length - 1)) }) _
           .OrderBy(Function(x) If(x.Head = "x", 1, If(x.Head = "y", 2, 3))) _
           .ThenBy(Function(x) If(x.Head = "x" Or x.Head = "y", -x.Value, x.Value)) _
           .Select(Function(x) x.Head & x.Value)

       For Each value In sortedArr
           Console.WriteLine(value)
       Next

       Console.ReadKey()

   End Sub
   ```

   End Module